Data resolution are not changing when try to minimize the resolution
In Firefox browser, when opened in normal form all data moves towards right, while it appears correctly in Chrome and Edge. Also when I tried to minimize the resolution in edge or chrome all data moves towards right.
When opened in Firefox Normally:

When Resolution is changed:

My CSS and other data:
<style> 

    /* Ensure consistent box-sizing across all elements */ 

    * { 

        box-sizing: border-box; 

    } 

    /* Adjust the layout of the DataTables top and bottom sections */ 

    .dataTables_wrapper .top, 

    .dataTables_wrapper .bottom { 

        width: 100%; 

    } 

 

    /* Add custom styles for the container */ 

    .container { 

        /* display: flex; 

                                    justify-content: space-between; */ 

        display: flex; 

        justify-content: space-between; 

        align-items: center; /* Center vertically */ 

    } 

 

     

 

 

    .table-container { 

        margin-top: 20px; 

        width: 100%; /* Ensure the container spans the full width */ 

        overflow-x: auto; /* Enable horizontal scrolling if necessary */ 

    } 

 

        .table-container table { 

            width: 100%; /* Ensure the table spans the full width of its container */ 

            border-collapse: collapse; 

        } 

 

        .table-container th, 

        .table-container td { 

            padding: 5px; 

            text-align: left; 

            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; 

            /*white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents text from wrapping */ 

        } 

 

        .table-container th { 

            background-color: #f2f2f2; 

            font-weight: bold; 

            /*white-space: nowrap; /* Prevents text from wrapping */ 

        } 

 

        .table-container tr:nth-child(even) { 

            background-color: #f2f2f2; 

        } 

 

        .table-container tr:hover { 

            background-color: #ddd; 

        } 

 

 

    #chart-container { 

        border: 2px solid #ddd; /* Border width, style, and color */ 

        padding: 10px; /* Add some padding inside the container */ 

        border-radius: 15px; /* Make the edges rounded (adjust the value as needed) */ 

        display: flex; 

        justify-content: space-between; 

        align-items: center; 

        gap: 20px; 

        margin-left: 0px; 

    } 

 

    canvas { 

        width: 250px !important; 

        height: 100px !important; 

    } 

 

    /* Style for the filter container */ 

    .filter-container { 

        display: flex; 

        justify-content: space-between; 

        align-items: center; /* Center vertically */ 

    } 

 

    /* Style for the filter div */ 

    .filter { 

        display: flex; 

        align-items: center; /* Center vertically */ 

    } 

 

 

    .table-container th:first-child, 

    .table-container td:first-child { 

        width: 50px; /* Adjust based on your checkbox width */ 

        text-align: center; 

    } 

 

 

    .table-container td.wave-number { 

        text-align: center !important; /* Center align wave number cells */ 

    } 

</style> 

 

My filter and table contents: 

<div class="filter-container"> 

    <div id="chart-container"> 

        <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">Overall Counts</h5> 

 

        <!--<canvas id="statusChart"></canvas>--> 

        <!-- Add this div to display the counts --> 

        <div id="statusCountsContainer"> 

            <div class="status-item"> 

                <span class="circle yellow"></span> Not Started: <span id="notStartedCount">0</span> 

            </div> 

            <div class="status-item"> 

                <span class="circle blue"></span> In Progress: <span id="inProgressCount">0</span> 

            </div> 

            <div class="status-item"> 

                <span class="circle green"></span> Completed: <span id="completedCount">0</span> 

            </div> 

            <!--<div class="status-item"> 

                <span class="circle greenyellow"></span> Completed Manually: <span id="completedManuallyCount">0</span> 

            </div>--> 

            <div class="status-item"> 

                <span class="circle red"></span> Failed: <span id="failedCount">0</span> 

            </div> 

            <!-- Search Field --> 

        </div> 

    </div> 

</div> 

<div class="table-container"> 

    <table class="table" id="deviceTable"> 

        <thead> 

            <tr> 

                <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"></th> 

                <th>Device Serial</th> 

</tr> 

        </thead> 

        <tbody id="deviceTableBody"> 

            @foreach (var item in Model) 

            { 

                <tr> 

                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="row-checkbox" data-id="@item.DeviceSerial"></td> 

                    <td>@item.DeviceSerial</td> 

                     

                     

        </tbody> 

    </table> 

</div> 

In javaScript  I have made applyResponsiveStyles() to handle it but not working also provided specific style for firefox but not working( navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') )
My JavaScript Code:
@section Scripts { 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.2/xlsx.full.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script> 

    <script> 

        var table; // Declare the table variable globally 

 

        $(document).ready(function () { 

            // Initialize DataTable 

            table = $('#deviceTable').DataTable({ 

                searching: true, 

                lengthChange: false, 

                dom: '<"top"lf<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>', 

                order: [[7, 'desc']], 

                paging: true, // Enable pagination 

                columnDefs: [ 

                    { orderable: false, targets: 0 } // Disable sorting on the first column 

                ] 

            }); 

            updateStatusCounts(); 

            populateWaveFilter(); 

            // Apply styles on page load 

            applyResponsiveStyles(); 

 

            // Add event listener for window resize 

            $(window).on('resize', applyResponsiveStyles); 

 

            // Inject Firefox-specific styles 

            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') !== -1) { 

                $('<style>').text(` 

                            /* Firefox specific adjustments */ 

                            .table-container table { 

                                table-layout: auto; /* Adjust table layout for Firefox */ 

                            } 

                        `).appendTo('head'); 

            } 

} 
    // Function to apply responsive styles 

function applyResponsiveStyles() { 

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(); 

 

    if (windowWidth <= 768) { 

        // Apply responsive styles 

        $('#chart-container').css({ 

            'flex-direction': 'column', 

            'gap': '10px' 

        }); 

 

        $('.filter-container').css({ 

            'flex-direction': 'column', 

            'gap': '10px' 

        }); 

 

        $('.search-container').css({ 

            'margin-left': '0', 

            'padding-top': '5px' 

        }); 

 

        // Adjust table styles 

        $('.table-container').css({ 

            'overflow-x': 'auto', 

            'margin-top': '20px' 

        }); 

 

        $('#deviceTable').css({ 

            'width': '100%' 

        }); 

 

        $('.table-container td').css({ 

            'padding': '5px', 

            'text-align': 'left', 

            'border-bottom': '1px solid #ddd' 

        }); 

 

        $('.table-container th').css({ 

            'background-color': '#f2f2f2', 

            'font-weight': 'bold' 

        }); 

 

    } else { 

        // Revert to default styles 

        $('#chart-container').css({ 

            'flex-direction': '', 

            'gap': '' 

        }); 

 

        $('.filter-container').css({ 

            'flex-direction': '', 

            'gap': '' 

        }); 

 

        $('.search-container').css({ 

            'margin-left': '', 

            'padding-top': '' 

        }); 

 

        // Reset table styles 

        $('.table-container').css({ 

            'overflow-x': '', 

            'margin-top': '' 

        }); 

 

        $('#deviceTable').css({ 

            'width': '' 

        }); 

 

        $('.table-container td').css({ 

            'padding': '', 

            'text-align': '', 

            'border-bottom': '' 

        }); 

 

        $('.table-container th').css({ 

            'background-color': '', 

            'font-weight': '' 

        }); 

    } 

} 

} 

Any help will be thankful, and let me know if any changes are required in above query
